# jQuery: hide table row

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is the function that is called when button delete is pressed. After confirmation of delete, I want to hide the delete tr :

```
function delete_confirmation(id) {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "To delete this patient!",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            $.ajax({
                url: localStorage.getItem("base_url") + '' + 'index.php/Patient_ws/delete/',
                timeout: 4000,
                type: "POST",
                data: ({id: id}),
            }).done(function () {
                $tr.remove();
            })
            .fail(function () {
                swal({
                    title: ' erreur in server, try later...',
                    type: 'warning'
                })
            })
        } else {
            swal("Patient not deleted");
        }
    });
}
```

Html markup:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="delete_confirmation(<?php echo $patient->id_personne;?>)">
<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete </a>
```

I want to hide tr - please help.

Comment: Please add some details to clarify "does not work". What happens? Nothing? Something other than what you wanted? Errors?

Comment: the delete request work. but after the confirmation the <tr> is not removed

Comment: I see. So the `<a>` with `onclick="delete_confirmation()"` is inside the `<tr>` you want to be removed, right? Just making sure

Comment: yes the tr that containe the button delete that i pressed will be removed after the confirmation of the delete action

Comment: when i write console.log(this): 
messege:Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}

Comment: Right because inline onclick has no `this` context of it's own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit `this` in an `onclick` function unless you pass it in from the html. Try `console.log(this)` will see it is probably `Window` and not the element

Since you are already using jQuery I would suggest also using it for the event listener and moving the php output to a data attribute

HTML

```
<a class="delete-row-btn btn btn-danger btn-xs" 
   data-id="<?php echo $patient->id_personne;?>">
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click','.delete-row-btn', delete_confirmation)

function delete_confirmation(event) {    
        event.preventDefault();
        // now `this` is the button
        var id = $(this).data('id')
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        // all else should be same
        swal({
              .....

}
```